# choosing an existing server diabled

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I'm using the Apache server Tomcat 8.5.93 version.
I try to create a program and make it run at the end, but I can't select the choosing an existing server part as shown.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruN2D.png)
I looked for a solution and found that the servlet version doesn't fit, but I was set to sevlet 3.1 which matches Apache Tomcat 8.5v.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tq8tv.png)

In this case, how can I get the project to run?

my Apache Tomcat is 8.5v and this is fit to servlet 3.1 that I set.

There may be other reasons why choosing an exiting server is not selected.

and I did this solution but it's not work.

<< Help --> Install new software ---> install " eclipse repository - https://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen ". Then install the package for -- Web,XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development. Reboot your computer and eclipse >>

please let me know what is the problem and how to fix it...

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen is more than six years and 22 releases behind. Please upgrade.